# Does Google's "Piñata Game" deserve a tag?

Tags: discussion

For those of you who don't know Google now has a game (it's where the Google) logo normally is, and it's where you hit the piñata then your score is based on how much candy you got out of it. I was going to ask a question for it, but I was wondering if it was deserving of tag since it's only a *very small* game. I understand that obscure games are allowed, but I'm not sure in this case.

I almost forgot to mention, as far as I can tell it's has no name.

I'd like some input. Does it need a tag or should I just not ask it?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: The only problem with the question would be would be if the game ceases to exist tomorrow.  Are the doodle games saved somewhere where people can play them again later?

Comment: @JasonBerkan Google seems to have an [archive](http://www.google.com/doodles/finder/2013/All%20doodles) of past doodle's, but I'm not sure if you can play the ones that aren't just images.

Comment: @JasonBerkan - Google's [pacman](https://www.google.com/doodles/30th-anniversary-of-pac-man) is still playable

Comment: Nothing deserves a tag until there is a question about it.

Comment: @Robotnik This isn't about a game without a tag, but rather whether or not a pseudo-game deserves one of its own. I wouldn't consider them duplicates.

Comment: [Hurdles 2012](http://www.google.com/doodles/hurdles-2012) is also still playable, so I guess they all stay playable after they're ditched from the front page.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Now there is a question

Answer (score 8):

Realistically, there's gonna be one question per game doodle and one game doodle every other week or so. So it's safe to assume we could just have them all under a collective [google-doodles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-doodles), sort of like a set of minigames. The tag wiki should probably include a note that you best link to / give a date for the doodle in question.

We also have the precedent (for [google-doodles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-doodles)) set by the [Zerg Rush Doodle (64300)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64300), we could just consolidate them all. (And probably also remove the uniquely identifying [google-zerg-rush](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-zerg-rush) there.)

Comment: `google-doodles` is basically a series tag though, which we only use when the question is relevant to the entire series.

Comment: @Ullallulloo I just doubt there's much use in what is inherently clutter tags.

Comment: Did you mean to say "gonna be *at most* one question per game doodle"?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That's one way to put it. I just assumed that, realistically, there's one possible (encompassing) question for each game, based on how simplistic they are.

Comment: @FEichinger Without the modifier of "at most", it sounds like you are saying there's going to be *exactly* one question for each game; never less or more. Since we currently have zero questions for a lot of them, it reads funny.

Comment: Meh, semantics.

Comment: +1 This seems like the best solution. Since most of the doodles don't have official names using specific tag for each game will probably just make it harder to find questions about those games, not easier. Since I doubt we'll be getting a bunch of questions about the doodles anyways a generic tag seems like our best bet.

Comment: @Wipqozn Very good point about the lack of official names. The more I think about this the more this seems like the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a game doesn't really matter when determining whether or not it deserves a tag, nor if it deserves to be asked about. If it's a game, no matter how small, you're allowed to ask a question about it.

With that said, though, if the Google Doodle game isn't going to be playable after the Google Clock hits midnight then your question is **Too Localized**, and will be closed for that reason.

Comment: http://www.google.com/doodles/googles-15th-birthday

Answer (score -1):

If someone has a question about it, then it they should definitely make a new tag about it. It doesn't matter how small it is.

Like Wipqozn said, localization could be a problem, but it should be available forever at http://www.google.com/doodles/googles-15th-birthday.

If you need a tag for it, [googles-15th-birthday](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/googles-15th-birthday) looks good. Maybe [googles-15th-bday-doodle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/googles-15th-bday-doodle) if you want doodle in the title.

Comment: Quite frankly, I'd recommend we just tag with [google-doodle] and specify the date/link to the archive in the question. There's, realistically, going to be one question per game. And one game every other week at best.

Comment: @FEichinger Please post that as a seperate answer so I can upvote it. Also, we have some other google-doodle based questions that could do with a retag.

Comment: @FEichinger Actually, [It exists!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-doodles)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: That's basically a series tag though, and not really needed on these questions. I think each game should just have it's own tag.

Comment: @Ullallulloo Considering the means of distribution, I tend to think of them as more akin to a collection of minigames. Like Mario Party. Except *substantially* less awesome.